# How do I validate/ read a yaml if I don't know the expected schema in (a struct) using go?

Tags: go, yaml

I am able to read this   using this library `"github.com/smallfish/simpleyaml"`

```
yml, err := ioutil.ReadFile("pvz-qa.yml")

    b := err == nil
    if b {
        fmt.Print("All good")

    }

    fmt.Print(yml)


    parsedYml,error := simpleyaml.NewYaml(yml)
```

Can I  do the same using `gopkg.in/yaml.v2` ?

Comment: „Better“ is very broad ...

Answer (score 1):

You can unmarshal to an interface:

```
var yml interface{}
data,_:=ioutil.ReadAll(file)
err:=yaml.Unmarshal(data, &yml)
```

Once you successfully unmarshal, `yml` is a `map[interface{}]interface{}`, and you can traverse the tree using type assertions. For instance:

```
value:=yml["key"]
```

will give you the value for the `key`, and you can check if it is a string, or `[]interface{}`, or `map[interface{}]interface{}` and descend recursively.